# ¿Cómo hacer para que la primera letra de cada palabra sea mayúscula en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de convertir un texto al momento que lo ingresen en mayúscula o en minúscula.

Me olvidé de agregar que tiene que ser automático, cuando uno escribe tiene que cambiar a mayúscula la primera letra de cada palabra; lo utilizaría para un `input` donde iría el nombre.

Estos son los posibles formatos de texto que se puede ingresar:

> 'TEXTO INGRESADO PRUEBA' 
> 'Texto Ingresado Prueba' 
> 'texto ingresado prueba'

Este código me funciona a medias, solo me cambia la primera letra pero la segunda ya no cambia.

```
$('input[id^=value_nombre]').keyup(function () {

    var num = $('input[id^=value_nombre]').val().toLowerCase();
    $("input[id^=value_nombre]").val(num.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + num.substr(1));
   
});
```

El resultado esperado debería ser:

> 'Texto Ingresado Prueba'

Comment: Hola, ¿Que has intentado? ¿Tienes algún ejemplo de código con el que estas trabajando? Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga mejor aceptación

Comment: ¿Por qué solo no usas css con `text-transform: capitalize;`?

Comment: necesito que al escribirse automáticamente cambie a mayúscula la primera letra de cada palabra

Answer (score 0):

Eso es más un tema de javascript que de jquery, acá dejo una función que hace lo que necesitas.

```
let split = string.split(" "); //Primero se verifica si el string ingresado es una palabra sola o viene separada por espacios :

if(split.length > 0) // Si es mayor a 0  significa que la palabra trae más de 1 palabra separada por un espacio, de lo contrario significa que es una única palabra.
```

Dependiendo de eso realizamos las operaciones necesarias

Te dejo una descripción de lo que hacen las funciones utilizadas :

```
string.toUpperCase() //Convierte una cadena en mayusculas
string.toLowerCase() //Convierte una cadena en minusculas
string.slice(1) // Devuelve toda la cadena excepto la primera letra.

function convert(string){
    let split = string.split(" ");
    let result = ""; 
    if(split.length > 0){
     for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
         result +=  split[i][0].toUpperCase() +  split[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()+    " ";
     }
    }else{
        result = string.toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: No puede uno limitarse a pegar un código y decirle: "toma, cámbialo por el tuyo". Cuando la gente pregunta no suele ser solo por  solución, también por una explicación de su error o de la forma de solucionar la duda. Te sugiero que edites tu respuesta y comentes en que consiste tu código y coo funciona. Un saludo

Comment: trate adaptarlo a mi codigo pero no trabaja bien, al momento de escribir separa las palabras

$('input[id^=value_nombre]').keyup(function () {

    var result="";
        miString = $('input[id^=value_nombre]').val().toLowerCase(); 

        miString =miString.split(" ");

        function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
            return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
        
  }
        for (var i=0; i < miString.length; i++) {
            result+=capitalizeFirstLetter(miString[i])+" "; 
        }
        $('input[id^=value_nombre]').val(result);

});

Comment: prueba de esta manera, me respondiste con una funcion que  yo no puse .     $('input[id^=value_nombre]').keyup(function () {
 var result=""; 
 miString = $('input[id^=value_nombre]').val();

result = convert(miString)


 $('input[id^=value_nombre]').val(result); 
 });
 function convert(string){
  let split = string.split(" ");
  let result = ""; 
  if(split.length > 0){
 for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
 result +=  split[i][0].toUpperCase() +  split[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()+    " ";}
}else{result = string.toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();}return result;
}

Comment: la función no funciona correctamente, separa cada letra con espacios.
$('input[id^=value_direccion]').keyup(function () { 
var result=""; miString = $('input[id^=value_direccion]').val(); 
result = convert(miString) 
$('input[id^=value_direccion]').val(result); 
}); 

function convert(string){ 
var split = string.split(" "); 
var result = ""; 
if(split.length > 0){ 
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) { 
result += split[i][0].toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()+ " ";} 
}else{
result = string.toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();}
return result; 
}

Comment: recuerda que cuando das una respuesta debes explicar que estas haciendo ... que hace cada método o funcion que implementes, las respuestas van dirigidas no solo al OP, tambien a la comunidad en general.

Answer (score 0):

Por si aun necesitas ayuda con esto tu solución es la siguiente:

Para que cada palabra del texto pase a mayúscula lo que puedes es, dividir el `String` en un `Array`, donde cada elemento serán cada una de las palabras del `String` y luego concatenarlos así:

```js
$('input[id^=value_nombre]').keyup(function () {
  
  var output = ''
  var input = $(this).val()
  var words = input.split(/\s+/) //Convertira el valor en un array, donde el separador es 1 o mas espacios en blanco

  $.each(words, function(index, value) {
    var a = value.charAt() //Sacamos la primera letra
    var b = value.slice(1) //Sacamos el resto de la palabra
    var word = a.toUpperCase() + b //Pasamos la primera letra a mayúscula y concatenamos
    
    output += word
    
    // Si no es el ultimo item, agregamos un espacio en blanco
    if(index != (words.length - 1)){
      output += ' '
    }
  })
  
  $(this).val(output)

});
```

Espero te sirva saludos

Answer (score -1):

Espero te sirva...

```js
function capitalice(text){ //declaramos la funcion capitalize que recibe un parametro de tipo string (solo recibira una palabra en el parametro)
    text = text.toLowerCase() //tomamos esa cadena y la pasamos completamente a minusculas con la funcion de string ".toLowerCase()" si era "holAndA" esto la dejaria "holanda"
    let firstLetter = text[0]  //declaramos la variable firsLetter que va a tener el valor del caracter en el indice "0" osea la primer letra de la cadena si se llamo capitalize("holAndA") entonces se seleccionara la letra "h" que es la que se encuentra en ese indice
    firstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase() // aqui convertimos esa letra en mayusculas con ".toUpperCase()" dejandola en la misma variable si era "h" la dejaria "H"
    text = text.slice(1) //aqui cortamos el string recibido desde el primer caracter si la variable texto es por ejemplo "holanda" con este metodo quedaria "olanda", si le pasamos como parametro otro numero cortala la cadena por donde se le indique
    let palabra = firstLetter + text // declaramos la variable palabra que sera igual a la suma de las dos string que contiene "firstLetter" y "text", por ejemplo "H" + "olanda", quedaria "Holanda"
    return palabra //devolvemos la cadena ya procesada con la primera letra en mayuscula
}

texto = 'holaNda munDaNA' //esta es la cadena que manejaremos

result = texto.split(' ') //tomamos la cadena de texto y la cortamos en los espacios con la funcion ".split()" que recibe como parametro en que caracter queremos cortar el string, en este caso devolveria ---> ['holaNda','munDaNa']
result.map(palabra=>{ //a result le pasamos el metodo de arrays ".map()" que itera entre todos los elementos de un array y recibe como parametro una funcion, en este caso un arrow function, a cada elemento se lo maneja con la variable "palabra" en este caso y como primera iteracion tomaria el valor de 'holaNda'
    return capitalice(palabra) //devuelve la palabra procesada por la funcion que en este caso como primera iteracion seria capitalice('holaNda') 
})

//para este punto result tendra como valor en este caso ['Holanda','Mundana']
 
result = result.join(' ') //con la funcion ".join()" unimos o concatenamos todo el array en una cadena como parametro recibe el "separador" que en este caso seran los espacios " ", quedando asi ".join(' ')"

console.log(result) // por ultimo mostramos el resultado en la consola
```

Comment: Saludos, antes de responder asegúrate siempre de que la pregunta se ajuste a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y segundo intenta siempre agregar una explicación al código que propones (como funciona y si es posible link de documentación), recuerda que hay usuarios que son nuevos en programación y no entenderán tu respuesta, de esta manera tus respuestas ganarán más puntos. ;)

Comment: Gracias, lo tendre en cuenta de ahora en mas

Comment: tampoco explicas tu codigo ... que significa esto: `text[0]?` que hace esto: `.slice(1)` y esto que es tambien: `.map(palabra=>` recuerda que cuando das una respuesta debes explicar que estas haciendo ... que hace cada método o funcion que implementes, las respuestas van dirigidas no solo al OP, tambien a la comunidad en general.

Comment: Brian, no lo tengas en cuenta de ahora en mas.. tenelo en cuenta en esta publicacion y en las proximas. Usa el boton [edit] y por favor explica que hace este codigo.

Comment: pido disculpas, no eh visto los mensajes antes, no volverá a suceder, saludos!